# Authenticating against WooCommerce REST API using OAuth 1.0

Tags: rest, woocommerce

How can I access WooCommerce REST API through HTTP by using OAuth 1.0 authentication method?

There was a document about this, but it is not clear for me.

[image: Woocommerce api error]

Comment: Which language are you implementing this in? There might be some client libraries available.

Comment: I want to develope mobile application with integeration of woocommerce(Live site to mobile App). I need to expose woocommerce rest api. Finally, I need json results for my woocommerce elements.
please mention if there is anyother way or idea to implement ..!!

Answer (score 0):

1) Set the HTTP method for the request:

```
GET
```

2) Set your base request URI – this is the full request URI without query string parameters – and URL encode according to RFC 3986:

> http://www.example.com/wc-api/v1/orders
>
> when encoded:
>
> http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fwc-api%2Fv1%2Forders

3) Collect and normalize your query string parameters. This includes all oauth_* parameters except for the signature. Parameters should be normalized by URL encoding according to RFC 3986 (`rawurlencode` in PHP) and percent(`%`) characters should be double-encoded (e.g. `%` becomes `%25`.

4) Sort the parameters in byte-order `(uksort( $params, 'strcmp'` ) in PHP)

5) Join each parameter with an encoded equals sign (`%3D`):

```
oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1
```

6) Join each parameter key/value with an encoded ampersand (`%26`):

```
oauth_consumer_key%3Dabc123%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1
```

7) Form the string to sign by joining the HTTP method, encoded base request URI, and encoded parameter string with an unencoded ampersand symbol (`&`):

`GET&http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fwc-api%2Fv1%2Forders&oauth_consumer_key%3Dabc123%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1`

8) Generate the signature using the string to key and your consumer secret key

If you are having trouble generating a correct signature, you’ll want to review your string to sign for errors with encoding. The authentication source can also be helpful in understanding how to properly generate the signature.

Taken from [here](https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication)

Comment: Please explain points from 4 to 8 in detail..
any example url for get the particuler product details ..!!

Comment: Can you please go into further details with this? 1) How do I set the method to GET and where? 2) How and where do I set the base request URI? I can find these info on many sites but nowhere I see a detailed tutorial on how to exactly execute them. Thank you